# Swapi Star Wars API Only Renders 10 Planets When Called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, react-fullstack

Note: I'm very new when it comes to rendering APIs.

Recently, I was assigned homework for calling and rendering API data from any API of our choosing. I chose the Swapi Star Wars API do it its high popularity. After choosing my API of choice, I was assigned to call and display all 60 planets within the Star Wars API. After wrestling with the API for the last two days, my calls to the API displayed only 10 sets of data. I've kept trying to utilize the useEffect and useCallback hooks for clean up purposes along with along with utilizing different conditions in order to set up and terminate a loop to get all sets of data but yet to no avail, I couldn't get the rest of the data to render. After utilizing Postman to display the data from the API call, I can't seem to find a definitive solution to display all 60 planets within the Swapi Star Wars API. Would be really appreciated if anyone can help me. Cheers.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);
  const [url, setURL] = useState(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets/`);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPlanets(){
      let res = await fetch(url);
      let data = await res.json();
      do{
        setPlanets(data.results);
        setURL(data.next);
      } while(data.next !== null)
    }
      fetchPlanets();
  },[planets, url]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {planets && planets.map((planet,i) => {
        return(
          <h1 key={i}>
            {planet.name}
          </h1>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Since it was your homework, I cannot just give you the solution, but I do read the documentation for awhile and try it for myself, it indeed show only 10 per page, means to get all 60, you need to call the API for 6 times and after each call save the data inside the setPlanets. Please notice that ?page= on the data returned.

Comment: SWAPI's pagination isn't documented, but as @nhk96 mentioned you just need to add the `?page=X` query parameter to the end. For example, https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=1 and https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=2 will give you 10 different planets.

Comment: @SaviorDaemon'sDragon can you show us the code you have tried? Maybe we can help you with that, again, it's your homework, we can't just show you the solution.